# Prisma data proxy npm script errors with 'DATABASE_URL' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: shell, npm, prisma

After creating a Prisma data proxy by following [this](https://www.prisma.io/docs/data-platform/data-proxy/use-data-proxy) guide, I switched the DATABASE_URL to my proxy connection string in my .env

```
DATABASE_URL="prisma://..."
```

I would like to migrate changes to my database. However, after reading [this](https://www.prisma.io/docs/data-platform/data-proxy/prisma-cli-with-data-proxy) from Prisma on how to migrate changes with their proxy, I refactored my .env vars to include another variable that will be used in an NPM script whenever I wish to migrate some changes (the script essentially swaps the proxy string with the cloud-hosted DB string)

Refactored `.env`

```
DATABASE_URL="prisma://..."

MIGRATE_DATABASE_URL="mysql://..."
```

Npm script inside `package.json`

```
{
  ...,
  "scripts": {
    "generate-client": "prisma generate --data-proxy",
    "migrate-deploy": "DATABASE_URL=\"$MIGRATE_DATABASE_URL\" prisma migrate deploy",
    "dev": "DATABASE_URL=\"$MIGRATE_DATABASE_URL\" prisma migrate dev",
  }
}
```

**The Problem**: whenever I run `npm run migrate-deploy`, I recieve this error:
'DATABASE_URL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: The error message you're seeing suggests that the system is unable to recognize the DATABASE_URL environment variable you're trying to set in the migrate-deploy script. One possible reason for this is that the script is being run in a shell that doesn't support setting environment variables in this way. One solution to this issue would be to prefix the command in the script with cross-env, it will allow you to set environment variables in a cross-platform way. Make sure you have installed cross-env package in your application `npm install cross-env`.

Comment: This worked, thank you! This was the final script i wrote : ``"db-push": "dotenv -e .env cross-env DATABASE_URL=\"$MIGRATE_DATABASE_URL\" prisma db push"`` I had to prefix it even more with dotenv to specify which env file to use since I had more than one. Please post your solution so I can mark it as answered